# Using include() instead of get_footer()

Tags: php, wordpress

Simple question. In a Wordpress template, is there a reason I shouldn't use `include()` and use `get_footer()` ?

Let's say I want to have a sub folder in my template directory with all my components included. This seems to work okay but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You shouldn't use `include()` in your Wordpress theme at all.**

The reason is that Wordpress' architecture is very pluggable - throughout core, plugins and themes, most components can interact with other components through [actions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [filters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference).

While `get_footer()` might seem simple, the functions that it runs allow parts of your theme to be overridden. In this case, [locate_template()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) allows a child theme to ship with a `footer.php` file in order to override the one set up by your main theme.

In addition, [get_footer()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/) itself allows the flexibility of including multiple footer files in your Wordpress theme so that you can call a slightly different footer on a particular template if you need to (by way of eg. `get_footer('alternative')` to call `footer-alternative.php` - which is then also overridable by a child theme).

---

It's worth noting that you should also ensure your footer template has a call to [wp_footer()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/) in it - ideally directly before the `</html>` tag. This goes back to what I mentioned above about actions and filters: in this case, any functions hooked to the footer by plugins or Wordpress core (such as script includes) will get run as intended (incidentally, `get_footer()` itself also runs the `get_footer` action, which allows eg. a plugin to override which footer template is called - this is thus another reason to use `get_footer()`).

Finally, in relation to not using `include()` in your theme at all, if you find yourself needing to include *another* template file that isn't a header or footer, [get_template_part()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) exists for that. While it sometimes may seem easier to just use native PHP functions rather than the wrappers the Wordpress architecture provides, in the end doing it the 'Wordpress way' means that your theme will interact better with plugins and future versions of Core, plus be more maintainable by others. And, you'll probably help avoid causing weird bugs for yourself too!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I wanted to use get_template_part() and get_footer() is there a way of sending variables into it? Functions? Singleton? What if you aren't making a theme to be sold or re-used and it's a one-time-use deal?

Comment: Anyone could come across this Q&A (and StackOverflow Q&A's are meant to be widely applicable) so it's best to refer you to best practice. In the end though, you can still do whatever you like whether it's a one-time-use theme or not ;) Still, doing it the 'wordpress way' will probably save you issues later on. In relation to sending variables in, [this answer on WPSE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176804/passing-a-variable-to-get-template-part) explains how.

Comment: @JamesHeazlewood Actually you could also potentially use a global variable... even though that's generally not good PHP, Wordpress (and its plugins) operate largely in the global namespace anyway so it's not necessarily an un-Wordpress thing to do. Just make sure it's named uniquely enough, etc.

Answer (score 2):

[get_footer()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L61) (click link for source) doesn't do anything further in the background rather than locate and include the file anyway.

`get_footer()` then calls [locate_template()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/template.php#L513) which then calls [load_template()](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.2/src/wp-includes/template.php#L560) which only does: `require_once($template_file)`

It's up to your preference but would recommend using `get_footer()` in case something does change in the future

Comment: This is slightly incorrect - using get_footer() allows a child theme to replace the footer introduced by a parent theme (via the theme location logic in `locate_template()`). I've added an answer that addresses and expands on this.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I saw that in the DocBlock but neglected to pay attention to it :D